# Creating shortcode id for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, php, shortcode

I want to create a custom shortcode for every employee/staff member.
I've allready got a custom post type plugin that i made, it creates a custom post type page. What i try to achieve is that i can create a shortcode like this `[medewerkers id=5]` or `[medewerkers id=1,2,3,4,5]` so i can choose which staff member to place on a certain page. In the following code that i found i only show the title of all members on a page when i type [medewerkers].

```
<?php
    add_shortcode( 'medewerkers', 'display_custom_post_type' );

    function display_custom_post_type(){
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'employee_infos',
            'posts_per_page' => '10',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_id' => null,
        );

        $string = '';
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( $query->have_posts() ){
            $string .= '<ul>';
            while( $query->have_posts() ){
                $query->the_post();
                $string .= '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
                $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), '');

            }
            $string .= '</ul>';
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        return $string;
    }
?>
```

The things that i'd like to show are the title, the content and the thumbnail image. thanks!

Grtz Willem

Comment: In the WordPress documentation in an good example of how to use the shortcode API with attributes [Shortcode API - codex.wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: Thanks! I will check this out for further information about my custom shortcode!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace the following code `$string .= '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';`.

to:

```
$string .= '<li>';
$string .= '<figure>' . get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'thumbnail' ) . '</figure>';
$string .= '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
$string .= '<div>' . apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ) . '</div>';
$string .= '</li>';
```

Hope it'll work just fine.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer! Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! It says this when i replace that. And i don't find the strings that much of a problem. I've got for example a post with id:60. The thing i want is that if i type shortcode [medewerkers id='60'] that the post with id:60 shows. Thanks